# Converting .sh to .bat

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file

I have a `.sh` file that I would like to convert to a `.bat` file. Below you can see my shell script and below that my sad attempt to convert the shell script to a batch file. I was able to covert some parts but other parts "stumped" me, like trying to echo the output of the `node pong.js $1` command to `__pongjs_output.txt`.

```
# Run a .php file both on pong.js and php and diff the output.

# Run on pong.js
node pong.js $1 > __pongjs_output.txt

# Run on node and replace some property names.
php $1 > __php_output.txt

echo "$1:"
diff __pongjs_output.txt __php_output.txt && echo "ok"

rm __pongjs_output.txt __php_output.txt
```

My attempt at converting the shell file to a batch file:

```
@ECHO off
REM Run a .php file both on pong.js and php and diff the output.

REM Run on pong.js
ECHO node pong.js %1 > __pongjs_output.txt

REM Run on node and replace some property names.
ECHO php %1 > __php_output.txt

ECHO %1:
FC __pongjs_output.txt __php_output.txt
IF errorlevel 0 ECHO ok

DEL __pongjs_output.txt __php_output.txt
```

Comment: Shouldn't `%1%` be `%1`?

Comment: If your need is to execute on windows machines an algorithm which is currently implemented in a shell script, you might want to consider using `cygwin`, a linux emulator that runs under windows, or `powershell`, a shell native to windows since Vista that has a syntax much more modern and closer to unix shells

Comment: @Tim I honestly have no clue.

Comment: @Aaron I looked into `cygwin` but I want the project to be "plug-n'-play." As for `powershell`, I completely forgot that it existed. I'm going to look into it though.

Comment: @nhabbott - I haven't done DOS batch file coding in a while, but I'm pretty sure `%1` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, `%something%` is for variables, `%x` for positional arguments and you have to use `%%x` in for loops for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (remove ECHO from before node and php):

```
@ECHO off
REM Run a .php file both on php.js and php and diff the output.

REM Run on pong.js
node pong.js %1 > __pongjs_output.txt

REM Run on node and replace some property names.
php %1 > __php_output.txt

ECHO %1:
FC __pongjs_output.txt __php_output.txt
IF errorlevel 0 ECHO ok

DEL __pongjs_output.txt __php_output.txt
```